# EF Core, Loads navigation property without Include() or Load()

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I have pretty basic code like that:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Linq;

var fooEntry = this.context.FooEntries.Single(r => r.Id == fooId);

public class FooEntity
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("NavigationPropertyId")]
    public SomeClass NavigationProperty { get; set; }

    public int NavigationPropertyId { get; set; }

}
```

In EF Core Lazy Loading isn't implemented. NavigationProperty should be loaded only if I use Eager Loading or Explicit Loading. But in my case, it loads NavigationProperty automatically. Why is that?

Comment: See the **Tip** from the EF Core documentation I mentioned in my answer to the linked post.

Comment: Amazing, thanks Ivan. It's off topic here, but how to act in a situation when you need to modify an entry and not to modify navigation property which is loaded occasionally. I scare that it produce unnecessary transaction against db.

Comment: There is no easy answer. Applying modifications of disconnected entities for sure can cause side effects. I would say make sure using short lived new db context instances when retrieving the data, thus controlling exactly what gets loaded.